# Using git push to create remote branch on the fly without creating local branch

Tags: git, github

So here is what i want to achieve:

When I clone a repository from Github and checkout some stable branch, and make some local changes in it, then I don't want to create a local feature branch nor do I want the changes to remain in the local stable branch that I have checked out.

I just want to make changes and push it to remote repo such that a feature branch is created there on remote, and my local stable branch remains clean.

How can this be done without creating a local branch and without the new changes to remain in local?

Answer (score 1):

#### checkout the remote stable branch

```
git fetch <remote> <branch>
```

Your local repo will now have a **read only** copy of the remote tracking branch, now check out to the read only tracking branch

```
git checkout origin/<branch_name>
```

Your VCS (whatever you are using) will start show messages like:

- `HEAD is in a detached state`
- `Previous HEAD position was c293198`

And the current branch as a hash fragment like `a697b40`.
All detached HEAD means is that making a new commit, then moving away from it (by checking out something else) will leave you with no reference to that new commit.

#### checkout and create the new "feature" branch from the remote tracking branch

```
git checkout -b "feature_branch_intended_for_remote"
```

At this point any commits will be added to this totally new branch - whose history was the original stable.
This means, you got the data of the remote stable (which you could not modify) and at no point did you create a local working copy of the upstream stable - which you might accidentally push back upstream.
So now you can now

- commit your work into this new branch
- push it back to the origin as a completely new branch

```sh
git push [--set-upstream | --track | -u] <remote> <feature_branch_intended_for_remote>
```